# vue cannot acces object props

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

i do a find method in an array to search for the object. I get back the object, but i can't acces the props in that object. The nuxt error thrower says the following:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

my code:

```html
<v-data-table :headers="datatable.headers" :items="datatable.items" class="elevation-1">
    <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
        <tr v-show="inMenu.find(menuItem => menuItem.name == item.name.toLowerCase()).value == true" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <!-- problem is in the <v-text-field> v-model -->
            <td><v-text-field v-model="settings.adminIcons.find(menuItem => menuItem.key == item.name.toLowerCase()).value" label="icon"></v-text-field></td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

the weird thing is, that if i do this:

```html
<!-- works -->
<v-text-field v-model="settings.adminIcons.find(menuItem => menuItem.key == 'evenementen').value" label="icon">
```

instead of this:

```html
<!-- does not work -->
<!-- item.name.toLowerCase() == 'evenementen' -->
<v-text-field v-model="settings.adminIcons.find(menuItem => menuItem.key == item.name.toLowerCase()).value" label="icon">
```

it will not work. but `item.name.toLowerCase()` is the same as 'evenementen'.

any solution?

Comment: Can you create a codepen or sandbox example ?

Answer (score 0):

It's giving error because in find it doesn't find any single item its return noting and you are trying to access `.value`.

```
// Error


//console.log(settings['adminIcons'].find(menuItem => menuItem.key == "env1").value)
```

```html
<script>
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

const settings = {
 'adminIcons':[
      {"key":"env",
        "value":"value1"}
     ]
}
const found = array1.find(element => element > 10);

console.log(settings['adminIcons'].find(menuItem => menuItem.key == "env").value);


// Error


//console.log(settings['adminIcons'].find(menuItem => menuItem.key == "env1").value);
</script>
```

Comment: find is returning an object

Comment: you have not understood what I was saying when find will not return any object it will give an error.

Comment: yes, you can conclude with this error that its not an object. But i can't find a solution how to do it otherwise. that's why i have this question on stackoverflow. i can diagnose that its not a object.

Comment: You can put v-if condition to check if the value is present or not.

Comment: <v-text-field v-if="settings.adminIcons.find(menuItem => menuItem.key == 'evenementen').hasOwnProperty('value')" v-model="settings.adminIcons.find(menuItem => menuItem.key == 'evenementen').value" label="icon">

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are accessing the value of item where item is not available in your data model.

This code will give you a string and this is where your error came from

```
menuItem.key == item.name.toLowerCase()) // if item.name = 'Test' will become 'test'.
```

Now, the returned of it it is not already the item you are accessing in your loop originally, rather give you a result but in new data. That's why when you are accessing it's value it say's that cannot read property value of undefined.

Comment: i need to find an item in an array. how would you achieve that with this code?

Comment: It's not what i give you code, but it's where the error coming from